# How to optimize ember-data with r.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, requirejs, ember-data

I recently switched to ember-data#canary, then `r.js` started failing.

```
 [Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 
     '/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data/core.js'
In module tree:
    app/main
      app/app
        ember-data

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
]
```

This is the build configuration file

```
`File: build.js`
    var config = {
        mainConfigFile: '/scripts/common.js',
    }
```

This is the requirejs configuration file

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ember: 'ember/ember',
        jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery',
        requirejs: 'requirejs/require',
        handlebars: 'handlebars/handlebars',
        'ember-data': 'ember-data/ember-data',
    },
    shim: {
        ember: {
            deps: [
                'handlebars',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Ember'
        },
        'ember-data': {
            deps: [
                'ember'
            ],
            exports: 'DS'
        },
    }
});
```

This is how i use `ember-data`:

```
define(['ember', 'ember-data'], function(Ember, DS) {
});
```

You can see the ember-data canary builds [here](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/canary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug have meet from ember-data 1.0.0-beta.9, because in this version has been updated function `require` in sources. You can revert to beta.8 or try to fix this problem with plugin [derequire](https://www.npmjs.org/package/derequire) (grunt-derequire, gulp-derequire).

I've fix it with this task:

```
gulp.task('build-derequire', function() {
return gulp.src([paths.src.common + '/bower_components/**/ember-data*.js'])
    .pipe($.derequire([
            {
                from: 'require',
                to: '_dereq_'
            },
            {
                from: 'define',
                to: '_defi_'
            }
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dev_dist + '/scripts/lib'));
});
```

Comment: Do you confirm this is a bug, and not something on my part? And if it is why do they introduce it intentionally, I mean why to they override requirejs variables? The minified version works ok.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Ember-data. For all I know, it will be fixed in the next beta version of ember-data.